# Perform operations within string format

Tags: ruby

I am sure that this has been asked, but I can't find it through my rudimentary searches.

Is it discouraged to perform operations within string initializations?

```
  > increment = 4
 => 4 
  > "Incremented from #{increment} to #{increment += 1}"
 => "Incremented from 4 to 5"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*I* sure wouldn't, because that's not where you look for things-that-change-things when reading code.

It obfuscates intent, it obscures meaning.

---

Compare:

```
url = "#{BASE_URL}/#{++request_sequence}"
```

with:

```
request_sequence += 1
url = "#{BASE_URL}/#{request_sequence}"
```

If you're looking to see where the sequence number is coming from, which is more obvious?

I can *almost* live with the first version, but I'd be likely to opt for the latter. I might also do this instead:

```
url = build_url(++request_sequence)
```

Comment: Okay. Thank you for that, however, I need to increment an integer every time that I make a network request, so I figured I would throw the increment into the URL path creation, rather than always having one extra line. I'm guessing it's still poor form, right?

Comment: @RileyE Depends; that's a very different example than what you provide. I still wouldn't, because it overloads the semantics of string interpolation in a way that could easily be overlooked.

Comment: It is very different, but you've firmly answered my question for most other cases. I think I will just create the habit of separating operations from string initialization and avoid all obfuscation. Thank you.

Comment: Worrying about one extra line is usually not too productive unless it's a duplicate of multiple other lines, at which point it becomes a "DRY" issue. If you need to do it multiple times, think about creating a separate method that takes a format string and make `increment` an instance or class variable and change it inside the method. And I'd rename `increment` to something else; it's a non-descriptive variable name.

Comment: Also, I am probably going to use a helper function in order to prevent the hassle of including the increment in the situation I referred to in my first comment.

Comment: @theTinMan The `increment` was only for this example, but I definitely want to avoid reiteration of code, so I will be aiming to create a nice helper function to prevent repeating myself and tiring out my poor little fingers.

Comment: @theTinMan But it describes *exactly* what it does! ;)

Answer (score 2):

In your particular case, it might be okay, but the problem is that the position where the operation on the variable should happen must be the last instance of the same variable in the string, and you cannot always be sure about that. For example, suppose (for some stylistic reason), you want to write

```
"Incremented to #{...} from #{...}"
```

Then, all of a sudden, you cannot do what you did. So doing operation during interpolation is highly dependent on the particular phrasing in the string, and that decreases maintainability of the code.

Comment: +1, good point; it makes refactoring/reordering more difficult under a variety of circumstances.